# MAX(count) + 1 when inserting, MySQL

Tags: mysql

I currently use the below query to increment the third column `count` on every insert.

```
$DB2->query("INSERT INTO relations (item_ID,tag_ID,count)
                    SELECT '$ID', '$tag_id', MAX(count) + 1
                    FROM relations
                    WHERE tag_ID = '$tag_id';");
```

The problem is when there is no rows in the table and i try to insert, the Max(count) + 1 is just null.  I've tried defining the default value as zero but still null.  The column should be `1` on first insert.

How do i change the query, so if first insert then `count` is 1.  I don't want to do a select query before because this code is in a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add an ifnull(...,1)

```
"INSERT INTO relations (item_ID,tag_ID,count)
                SELECT '$ID', '$tag_id', ifnull(MAX(count) + 1,1)
                FROM relations
                WHERE tag_ID = ''$tag_id';");
```